# create dataframe with multiple conditions keeping the NA entries

Tags: r, dataframe, na

I have three tables A, B and C each with a couple of columns with different values. 
I want to create a new data frame with the rows from each table that meet 2 conditions but I also want the rows with NA to output NA:

```
A=read.table(file.choose(),header=TRUE,row.names=1,sep="\t")
B=read.table(file.choose(),header=TRUE,row.names=1,sep="\t")
C=read.table(file.choose(),header=TRUE,row.names=1,sep="\t")
newtable = data.frame(V1=A$X1>2 | A$X2<0.05, V2=B$X1>2 | B$X2<0.05, V3=C$X1>2 | C$X2<0.05)
```

I get only the rows that meet the conditions with TRUE or FALSE but I don't get the rows where there was NA, however if I use only one condition

```
newtable = data.frame(V1=A$X1<0.05, V2=B$X1<0.05, V3=C$X1<0.05)
```

Then I get something like this:

```
A   B   C
1 TRUE  TRUE TRUE
2 TRUE FALSE TRUE
3 TRUE FALSE TRUE
4   NA    NA   NA
5   NA    NA   NA
```

Which is what I want (but with the two conditions).

Any suggestions?

Edited:
Example of input tables:

```
table A:
     X1          X2
1    4.4923656   0.03201e-02
2    -0.3764287  0.00747e-07
3    -0.7192387  0.00523e-12
4     NA         NA
5    -3.6088963  NA
6     NA         NA

table B:

     X1           X2
1    4.256852     0.04948311
2    -0.12365814  0.990901
3    1.2365852    0.21697529
4     NA          NA
5    7.2569852    NA
6     NA          NA

table C:
     X1          X2
1    8.1254874   0.074346e-02
2    -0.4587125  6.658373e-10
3    2.3256984  4.527989e-03
4     NA         NA
5    -4.2365874  NA
6     NA         NA
```

Comment: I can't tell if you have answered your own question or not. can you replace `A <- read.table` with the `dput(A)` and repeat for b and c?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying to accomplish? If you provide reproducible data I might be able to help more. You will need to install dplyr.

```
A <- data.frame(X1 = c(3,5,7), X2 = c(4,7,9), X3 = c(6,7,"NA"))
B <- data.frame(X1 = c(7,5,7), X2 = c(4,7,9), X3 = c(6,7,9))
C <- data.frame(X1 = c(9,5,7), X2 = c(5,7,9), X3 = c(6,7,9))

newtable = data.frame(V1 = dplyr::filter(A, X1 >3 & X2 >4))
newtable

    V1.X1 V1.X2 V1.X3
1     5     7     7
2     7     9    NA
```

Comment: You could do that with `subset` too

Comment: Yes, I didn't pose the question in the right way. I don't wan't an NA when the condition is not met, when the condition is not met I actually get FALSE, so I want to output the NA when the element in that row already had an NA. I edited the question to show the input tables.

Comment: I tried dplyr::filter and I get the error: Error in data.frame(V1 = dplyr::filter(A, X1>3 & X2>  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 8719, 9556, 9179

Comment: I'm not sure why you are getting that error. Maybe because each new variable you are creating has different number of rows? Try saving the new variables as vectors instead of a data frame.  After re-reading your question, I think you actually just want to include `NA` as a value to filter for? ie `newtable = data.frame(V1=A$X1>2 | A$X2<0.05 | A$X1=="NA")`.